# How to call method of an app from another app in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to call a method of an application A from my another application B's code in ios and also want to pass arguments.

Is it possible with socket programming if yes than please give some idea about how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: here is NO public api for inter process comm

Answer (score 1):

The only interprocess communication allowed by Apple on the AppStore is using URL handlers.

For more information, read [here](http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/).

Comment: thanks leo. I tried URL handler for communication between two apps A and B.If i call method of project B from A, Project B starts on main thread and A goes in background.

Comment: Sorry, this is the only thing available currently.

Comment: That is, if you wish to target the AppStore. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Using x-callback-url’s source apps can launch other apps passing data
>   and context information, and also provide parameters instructing the
>   target app to return data and control back to the source app after
>   executing an action.

Please refer this [link](http://x-callback-url.com/) for tutorials and sample code.

Comment: what leo said. ..just with a more concrete link

Comment: I need that the target app B should perform its task in background when calling from project A.But when i am calling project B from A, Project A goes in background and B's UI show up to user.

Comment: @poonam With iOS7 this can be achieved.